# Can I manually pin memory for use with CUDA?

Tags: linux, memory, cuda

I have an existing Linux application that I'd like to accelerate with CUDA. The application streams data in from another process, applies some signal processing operations to that data, and streams the data out to a follow-on process ("process" in this sense refers to the term in the operating systems sense).

The IPC method for streaming the data is dictated by the framework in which my application runs. Namely, named shared memory blocks are used as circular buffers between each process: when my application has data available at its output, it writes it to the shared memory block in a circular fashion.

For maximum throughput of the CUDA version of my application, I would like to overlap all of the following:

1. The copying the `N`-th block of input data to the device.
2. The processing of the `N-1`-th block of input data by the device.
3. The copying of the `N-2`-th block of output data from the device to the host.

From what I understand, to achieve overlap with all of these operations, I must use pinned memory on the host. However, my input/output shared memory buffers are allocated by the framework, which is outside of my control; I can't make it allocate pinned memory. I could do copies to intermediate buffers, but this increases the memory footprint of my application, which is undesirable. Ideally, I'd like to pin the existing shared memory buffers instead.

Is there a way that, given an arbitrary block of virtual memory, I can pin it such that it is suitable for use with asynchronous overlapped CUDA memory copies? Based on its man page, the `mlock()` function sounds like it might do what I want. Are there any pitfalls to be found here?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It will take more time to try an end-to-end test, but to verify your claims above, I added a call to `cudaHostRegister()` with my shared memory segment address and size. It returned `cudaSuccess`, indicating that it didn't fail. I haven't verified that the memory actually behaves as if it is pinned with respect to CUDA device operation, however.

Comment: OK, I tried it and it failed for me. I may have done something wrong, or it may be OS-specific.

Comment: `mlock` is what you are looking for indeed. On Linux it should do what you are asking for.

Comment: When using cudaHostRegister and mlock, I believe you have some alignment restrictions. If not satisfied, you get some error. Not to mention OS limits of course. Lock'n'Register aligned containing pages should work if OS limits are satisfied.

Comment: I tested driver api with `cuHostRegister` on non-multiple-of-4096 and non-aligned-to-4096 arrays and it did not give any error and worked for a simple kernel too(although 3x slower) but I didn't stress windows' page memory in that time. Does it give error when windows "move" that cuHosRegister'd memory instead?

Comment: Landed here with the same question. I think it is interesting for other scenarios too. Perhaps you have multiple devices/contexts and you want a pool of host memory allocations that are all pinned and can be DMA'd to any device/context - the standard pinned host allocation ties the memory to the current context, and fails if there isn't a current context.